Can a rain-resistant roof be constructed out of grass?
<Out of boredom> I'm building a tiny hut(0.5 persons can fit inside comfortably) with only natural materials i.e. sticks and stones. Trouble is there aren't any large-leaf plants around. Baking roof tiles is beyond me. Can ordinary grass be coached to provide protection against a medium rain(say 10 mm)?

if you're willing to stretch grass to reeds, straw, or strips of leaves... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thatching

Wood made into shingles?

@Willeke nah - first of all doing it with a rusty hand saw would take forever and secondly I have little access to branches thicker than say 20 cm.

@KateGregory - thanks for the name, no idea how had it escaped me. And now for the long process of reading and watching yt videos and trying and and failing until one day I can post a picture of it withstanding a moderate rain.

Shingles are usually made out of sections of trunks and at least something to split those. So not for you, maybe for someone who reads this question.

@Vorac a traditional reed thatched roof can withstand much more than 1 cm of rain.

@WeatherVane I'm sure of that. However my current reading conclusions are that 2 of the paramount factors in thatched roof quality are long grass(preferably 1.8m) and thatcher skill - neither of which I have. It's gonna be fun!

Check out https://www.youtube.com/@primitivetechnology9550/videos - they cover a lot of how-do-I-do-X-with-Y type of questions.  Including, I would think, making stuff rainproof.  But I don't know if it covers your particular constraints.

Can you use a manufactured natural material such as canvas? A canvas tent is waterproof until you touch the inner surface.
